How do you change a wordpress theme body colour in the theme.json file?
From what I've understood, Wordpress is encouraging using the theme.json file to style up a theme rather than using css files to target specific classes. I've figured out how to style buttons and specific blocks but I'm still at an odds on how to for example change the background colour of the header in the theme.json file, or perhaps change the body colour too.
I did try targeting the body in css and applying the background colours I wanted but this caused unexpected behaviour in the full site editor. What is generally considered best practice? Is there a way to do it in the theme.json?
I know I can edit those colours in the FSE directly but surely it would be good to get those base styles injected into the theme files instead?
Appreciate any and all help, quite new to Wordpress Block themes
